# Remove variable with zero variance

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, variance

Could somebody help me in writing the code to remove the variable whose variance is zero in the data frame using python?

Comment: Welcome to SO, which does is about *specific coding* questions and not a tutorial or code writing service. Please go through the help system to see how & what topics you can ask about here; we are more than happy to help you resolving issues with your code, but we cannot write your code for you.

Comment: Variance of zero means that that variable has not changed its value. So, based on your context, I could be as simple as finding how many unique elements that variable has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Removing features with low variance**

```
X = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
```

There are 3 boolean features here, each with 6 instances. Suppose we wish to remove those that are constant in at least 80% of the instances. Some probability calculations show that these features will need to have variance lower than 0.8 * (1 - 0.8). Consequently, we can use  [Ref: Scikit link](https://riptutorial.com/scikit-learn/example/17328/low-variance-feature-removal)

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))    
sel.fit_transform(X)
```

Output will be:

> ```
>       array([[0, 1],
>              [1, 0],
>              [0, 0],
>              [1, 1],
>              [1, 0],
>              [1, 1]])
> ```